# Gronwall's inequality for higher order derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Gronwall's inequality says that solutions to the initial value problem $u'(t) \leq \beta(t)u(t)$ with $u(0)=u_0$ are bounded by solutions to the problem with inequality replaced with equality for $t\in [0,\infty)$. Is there a way to generalize to higher order derivatives. That is, if $u''(t) \leq \alpha(t)u'(t) + \beta(t)u(t)$ with $u(0)=u_0$ and $u'(0)=u'_0$ can we say that the solutions to the corresponding differential equation dominates $u$?